# Synology: understanding the group service permission

Tags: permissions, nas, synology, user-groups, synology-diskstation

Let's say I have a user group A and user group B. I want A to have access to the FTP service and nothing else. I want B to have access to the cloud drive service and nothing else.

[image]

[image]

Now if I add a user Bob and want him to be part of group A **AND** group B, I'd expect him to have access to FTP **AND** cloud drive. However when I add him to the two groups, both restrictions cancel themselves. Bob ends up having access to nothing. Like in the images below ("Refuser" means "Denied" in French):

[image]

[image]

Should I explicitely give permission per users? If so, what's the point of groups? What do I miss here?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can uncheck both *Allow* and *Deny*. This will make users in this group inherit permissions from the default setting, so make sure access is denied by default:

*Control Panel* → *Applications* → *Privileges* → *Grant this privilege to all users by default* column unchecked

*Deny* is designed to always override *Allow* for security, but this way no group denies access, so they will combine nicely.

Comment: How wow. Ok, everything is clear now. Thanks a lot!